# How to read CSV in Pandas data frame when each cell has the header label?

Tags: pandas, csv

I am trying to read a log file CSV that has header labels in each cell. Is there an elegant way to do it apart from column by column handling of strings and removing the labels?

[image]

Comment: It looks like a json file rather than a csv file. What happens if you try to parse it as json?

Comment: Don't show data as images, provide them as text, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example